# MEAN stack routing issues

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I just downloaded and started playing with the MEAN stack(https://github.com/linnovate/mean), everything works fine until i try and additional routes.

```
//app/routes/hello.js:

'use strict';
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next, id) {
        console.log(req);
        res.json(123456);
    });
};
```

If i log app.routes to I can see the route:

```
{ path: '/hello',
  method: 'get',
  callbacks: [Object],
  keys: [],
  regexp: /^\/hello\/?$/i 
}
```

I have tried curling to

```
curl http://localhost:3000/hello -Method GET
```

I get 404.

But if i get /articles (which is one of the sample routes in MEAN.IO)

```
curl http://localhost:3000/articles -Method GET
```

It works just fine. 
Sitting a couple of hours now and really cant see any difference in how the routes are setup. But the ones included by default works, all routes i try to add myself renders 404.

So to conclude, clean MEAN.IO fork. Default routes work, routes i add, results in 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the route config to:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req);
        res.json(123456);
    });
};
```

Made it work, don't really know why.

Answer (score 0):

why there is a **fourth parameter(id)** in the callback function inside app.

**req -Request

res-Response

next-to pass the control to next function.**

**Try this:**

```
'use strict';
 module.exports = function(app, passport) {
 app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    res.json(123456);
  });
 };
```